# Watch doesn't get fire/trigger when global property change

Tags: vue.js, plugins, watch, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I’m very new to Vue and I begin with Vue 3. I was trying to migrate a template from Vue 2 to Vue 3 so I can start with my project.

I have this plugin file.

**Sidebar\Index.ts**

```js
import SidebarPlugComp from './SidebarPlugComp.vue'
import SidebarLinkPlugComp from './SidebarLinkPlugComp.vue'


// tiny internal plugin store
const SidebarStore = {
    showSidebar: false,
    sidebarLinks: [],
    displaySidebar (value: boolean) {
        this.showSidebar = value
    }
}

const SidebarPlugin = {
    install (app: any) {
    
        app.config.globalProperties.$sidebar = SidebarStore
        app.component('side-bar-plug-comp', SidebarPlugComp)
        app.component('sidebar-link-plug-comp', SidebarLinkPlugComp)
    }
}

export default SidebarPlugin
```

Also I have a **BaseTopNavLay** layout file so I can toggle the sidebar with *handleSidebarToggle* onclick button method

```js
<template>
    \\...
                <div class="navbar-toggle d-inline" :class="{toggled: $sidebar.showSidebar}">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="navbar-toggler"
                            aria-label="Navbar toggle button"
                            @click.prevent="handleSidebarToggle">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
                    </button>
   \\   ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    import { ModalComp } from '../components'

   
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'BaseTopNavLay',
        components: {
            ModalComp
        },
        // ...
        methods: {
            handleSidebarToggle (): void {
                this.$sidebar.displaySidebar(!this.$sidebar.showSidebar)
            },
            handleHideSideBar (): void {
                this.$sidebar.displaySidebar(false)
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

And here is the *watch* in the **App.vue** file

```js
<template>
    <component :is="this.$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
        <router-view />
    </component>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'


    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'Application',
        methods: {
            toggleNavOpen () {
                console.log('here')
                let root = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
                root.classList.toggle('nav-open')
            }
        },
        /*watch: {
            '$sidebar.showSidebar': function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log(newVal, oldVal)
            }
        }*/
        mounted () {
            //@ts-ignore
            this.$watch('$sidebar.showSidebar', this.toggleNavOpen)
        }
    })

</script>
```

Wherever I test the var `this.$sidebar.showSidebar` I can access to its value properly. Also, the onclick method is changing the `SidebarStore` object in Sidebar\Index.ts plugin file.

Can anyone give me a hint what am I missing here? Why the watch doesn't get fired. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not made your `$sidebar` reactive, and a `watch` needs to use a reactive variable.

You can keep the store where you have it, but I'd put it into a separate file (store.js) and import where needed, no need to put it on `app.config.globalProperties.$sidebar` (but that might be a personal preference

```js
// store.js
// using reactive (all values)
export const SidebarStore = Vue.reactive({
    showSidebar: false,
    sidebarLinks: [],
})
// or using ref (one for each)
// export const showSidebar = Vue.ref(false);

export const displaySidebar = (value: boolean) => {
    SidebarStore.showSidebar.value = value;
}
```

this will make `SidebarStore` and `displaySidebar`  available anywhere in your code

use like this

```html
<template>
    \\...
                <div class="navbar-toggle d-inline" :class="{toggled: $sidebar.showSidebar}">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="navbar-toggler"
                            aria-label="Navbar toggle button"
                            @click.prevent="handleSidebarToggle">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
                    </button>
   \\   ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    import { ModalComp } from '../components'
    import { SidebarStore, displaySidebar } from '../store'

   
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'BaseTopNavLay',
        components: {
            ModalComp
        },
        // ...
        methods: {
            handleSidebarToggle (): void {
                displaySidebar(!SidebarStore.showSidebar)
            },
            handleHideSideBar (): void {
                displaySidebar(false)
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, that solved the issue. I'm using the `app.config.globalProperties.$sidebar` 'cause i'm studying all this and found it in the vue3 docs. And you are right, is better separate the store in another file. Thanks again .

Comment: Glad it worked. On a side note, if you're building a large app/project I'd recommend that you consider using `vuex` to manage your global store.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Daniel, I'm going to use vuex 'cause the future size of the app and to benefit the traceability and maintainability of the code.